# Add Google API to existing eclipse project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am writing an android app that will use  Google Maps but to implement this I need the Google API. When I downloaded the android platform sdk (example android 4.0) I did not download the Google API cause did not know that I would need it to implement  this feature.However, I went back and downloaded it. How do I add it to my existing project. Did some searching and all showed how to start a new project with the API but not how to add it to the existing project.

Comment: Android does not use the Google Maps API V3. (tag removed)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have already downloaded the Google APIs for the version that you are developing for, example Android 4. all you have to do is:

`Right click on your project -> Go to Properties -> Then Android - > Then select the Google APIs at API level 14`

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple thing. In your file which you need the google maps api which  extends 'Activity', replace Activity with MapActivity. It should have a red line showing error on your code. hover mouse over it and click on the option 'Fix Project Setup'. you will then find an option that suggests you to import Google APIs. select it, and you are done.
Let me know if that works.